# HttpResponseRedirect that will redirect you to your second last page

Tags: django

I'd like to ask a questions. is there any way to use `HttpResponseRedirect` that will redirect you to your second last page. I'm trying to use `HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))` however it only redirects me to the last page.

Comment: Is this a fixed page you want to redirect to, or dependent on the situation? Or do you want to redirect to the previous page in case of a form submission where you have an additional post request?

Comment: depends on the situation. something like history.go(-2). I wanted to let it return to the second previous page since it will already delete the previous page

Comment: The view should find the correct page to redirect to based on the situation and shouldn't be hard to code that logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return HttpResponse('<script>history.go(-2)</script>')
```